# What's wrong code if-else with tag script?

Tags: if-statement, unity-game-engine, tags

[hirarky](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPR2R.jpg)Hello I have the right panel and the wrong panel, the panel is used to check whether the object is dragging and dropping in the right slot. but in this code, when I run the wrong panel it always appears first, before I drag and drop the object. even though I have set it to be inactive. what should I fix ?

```c#
public class CekBenar3 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float delay = 1;

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject PanelBenar;

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject PanelSalah;

    void Start()
    {
        PanelBenar.SetActive(false);
        PanelSalah.SetActive(false);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Slot1.cek1 && Slot2.cek2 && Slot3.cek3)
        {
            GameObject objek1 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Benar1");
            GameObject objek2 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Benar2");
            GameObject objek3 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Benar3");

            if (objek1.transform.parent.tag == "Jawab1" 
                && objek2.transform.parent.tag == "Jawab2" 
                && objek3.transform.parent.tag == "Jawab3")
            {
                PanelBenar.SetActive(true);
            }
            else
            {
                PanelSalah.SetActive(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your game objects hierarchy?

Comment: yes, this is the hierarchy screenshots file

Comment: There is still not enough information. What is `Slot1.cek1`? What object is  `Benar1`? What object is tagged `Jawab1`? My guess as to your problem is that you're trying to validate all 3 objects at the same time (you can't: only one is being dragged). I'm also pretty sure that the tag if-statement is always true (no code changes the tags here, and GameObject.Find presumably always returns the same object).

Comment: Recommendation: don't code in Indian. Even if you do, don't expect people on SO to know Indian and be able to read your code.

Comment: hello if I may ask again. I have a problem with if statment on onmousedown. they can't read which button 1.2 or 3 is clicked. how should I handle it, please help me `public GameObject karakter; public GameObject ButtonLevel1; public GameObject ButtonLevel2; private void OnMouseDown() { if (ButtonLevel1) { Debug.Log("a"); } if (ButtonLevel2) { Debug.Log("b"); }}`